# How can i print characters diagonal with loop in assembly

Tags: loops, assembly, x86-16, dosbox

```
CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:CODE
START:  

MOV AH,06h ;INT 10,6
MOV AL,00h ;number of lines to scroll, previous lines are
;blanked, if 0 or AL > screen size, window is blanked
MOV CH,00h ;row of upper left corner of scroll window
MOV CL,00h ;column of upper left corner of scroll window
MOV DH,24h ;row of lower right corner of scroll window
MOV DL,79h ;column of lower right corner of scroll window
MOV BH,07h ;attribute to be used on blank line
INT 10h



MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,01H
MOV DL,03H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,02H
MOV DL,06H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,03H
MOV DL,0AH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,04H
MOV DL,0DH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,05H
MOV DL,10H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,06H
MOV DL,14H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,07H
MOV DL,17H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,08H
MOV DL,1AH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,09H
MOV DL,1EH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,0AH
MOV DL,21H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,0BH
MOV DL,24H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,0CH
MOV DL,28H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,0DH
MOV DL,2BH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,0EH
MOV DL,2EH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,0FH
MOV DL,32H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,10H
MOV DL,35H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,11H
MOV DL,38H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,12H
MOV DL,3CH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,13H
MOV DL,3FH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,14H
MOV DL,42H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,15H
MOV DL,46H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,16H
MOV DL,49H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,17H
MOV DL,4CH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,18H
MOV DL,50H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h


;-------------------------------------------------------




MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,01H
MOV DL,4DH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,02H
MOV DL,4AH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,03H
MOV DL,46H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,04H
MOV DL,43H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,05H
MOV DL,40H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,06H
MOV DL,3CH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,07H
MOV DL,39H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,08H
MOV DL,36H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,09H
MOV DL,32H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,0AH
MOV DL,2FH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,0BH
MOV DL,2CH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h



MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,0DH
MOV DL,25H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,0EH
MOV DL,22H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,0FH
MOV DL,1EH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,10H
MOV DL,1BH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,11H
MOV DL,18H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,12H
MOV DL,14H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,13H
MOV DL,11H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,14H
MOV DL,0EH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,15H
MOV DL,0AH
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,16H
MOV DL,07H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,17H
MOV DL,04H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h

MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DH,18H
MOV DL,01H
INT 10H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
INT 21h





int 20h
CODE ENDS
END START
```

That is the manual way what i want to do :).I want to increase or decrease cursor's row,column number within loop,and i tried this code

```
CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:CODE
START:  

MOV CX,12
MOV DH,00H
MOV DL,00H

dongu:
MOV AH,02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV AH,02h
MOV DL,2Ah
inc dl
inc dh
INT 10H
loop dongu

INT 21h
int 20h
CODE ENDS
END START
```

But it isn't working well.

By the way sorry for my bad english and this is my first post to stackoverflow.

Comment: 'Isn't working well' is not a error description. Either you have particular error you are dealing with or major understanding problems. Please be as precise as possible, otherwise we can't/don't want to help you.

Comment: Indeed there is not exist any error.I couldn't print '*' character diagonally.I shared the manual way for more intelligibility.I will try to be more careful about rules.Thanks for reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Preamble

> ```
> MOV AH,06h ;INT 10,6
> MOV AL,00h ;number of lines to scroll, previous lines are
> ;blanked, if 0 or AL > screen size, window is blanked
> MOV CH,00h ;row of upper left corner of scroll window
> MOV CL,00h ;column of upper left corner of scroll window
> MOV DH,24h ;row of lower right corner of scroll window
> MOV DL,79h ;column of lower right corner of scroll window
> MOV BH,07h ;attribute to be used on blank line
> INT 10h
> ```

The above snippet already shows an error. You're confused about decimal and hexadecimal numbers. The coords for the lower right corner are (79,24). You have written much larger values (79h,24h)=(119,36). If you're lucky the BIOS won't mind too much, but you cannot count on this leniency.

> ```
> MOV AH,02H
> MOV BH,00H
> MOV DH,18H
> MOV DL,50H     <<<<< This is off-screen!
> INT 10H
> MOV AH,02h
> MOV DL,2Ah
> INT 21h
> ```

The last point for the 1st diagonal is off-screen. In the solution that follows I'll correct this.

> ```
> inc dl
> inc dh
> ```

In your attempt to code a loop that produces a diagonal on the screen, you won't get away with just incrementing/decrementing the cursor's position because

- the screen isn't square, meaning `DL` and `DH` don't change in unison.
- the horizontal dimension is much larger than the vertical dimension, meaning the horizontal step is 3 or 4 where the vertical step can remain at 1.

---

### Solution

For a simple solution that will produce the exact same output as your manual version, you can store the coords to use in an array and then loop over this data. Because the row can indeed use incrementing by 1 there's no need to store the vertical component. Because the 2nd diagonal is symmetrical to the 1st one, there's no need to store separate data for this 2nd diagonal **(*)**.
Next code will give the 1st diagonal from (3,1) to (79,24)

```
array   db 3,6,10,13,16,20, ... ,73,76,79,-1
    ...
    mov     cx, 1        ;Repetition count for BIOS function 09h
    mov     bx, 0007h    ;BH=Display page 0, BL=Attribute WhiteOnBlack
    mov     si, array
    mov     dh, 0        ;Row
again:
    inc     dh           ;Vertical step is fixed at 1
    mov     dl, [si]     ;Column
    mov     ah, 02h      ;SetCursor
    int     10h
    mov     ax, 092Ah    ;AH=BIOS function 09h, AL=Character "*"
    int     10h
    inc     si
    cmp     byte ptr [si], -1  ;Reached end of list marker?
    jne     again
```

Please note that I didn't use DOS function 02h to output the character. Since this DOS output function advances the cursor automatically, it will at some point disturb your screen. The BIOS output function that I did use, does not advance the cursor and thus is perfect for your program.

### Look closely (*)

```
array1  db 3,6,10,13,16,20, ... ,73,76,79,-1
array2  db 77,74,70,67,64,60, ... ,7,4,1,-1
```

If you look closely at the numbers for the 2nd diagonal, you should see that there's a resemblance with the numbers for the 1st diagonal. Indeed the column is now complementary with the width of the screen:

```
77 = 80 -  3
74 = 80 -  6
70 = 80 - 10
...
 4 = 80 - 76
 1 = 80 - 79
```

Now we can exploit this to write the loop for the 2nd diagonal with only minor changes to the code:

```
array   db 3,6,10,13,16,20, ... ,73,76,79,-1
    ...
    mov     cx, 1        ;Repetition count for BIOS function 09h
    mov     bx, 0007h    ;BH=Display page 0, BL=Attribute WhiteOnBlack
    mov     si, array
    mov     dh, 0        ;Row
again:
    inc     dh           ;Vertical step is fixed at 1
    mov     dl, 80                              <<<<< Only changes
    sub     dl, [si]     ;Column                <<<<< Only changes
    mov     ah, 02h      ;SetCursor
    int     10h
    mov     ax, 092Ah    ;AH=BIOS function 09h, AL=Character "*"
    int     10h
    inc     si
    cmp     byte ptr [si], -1  ;Reached end of list marker?
    jne     again
```

---

I realize that there's probably a lot of new stuff in this answer. Do take the time to understand each line of the code I've written. Don't satisfy yourself just copying it. When in doubt, don't hesitate to post comments about this answer! You're welcome.